# jQuery datepicker Alert Validation

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm having problem in `jQuery datepicker`. All I want to do is there will be alert validation for the  dateFormat of my datepicker.

all i want to do is:

```
if(mydatepicker!= dateFormat) { alert('Invalid Date Format!'); }
```

just exactly like that..

here is my code:

```
    $('#BirthDate').datepicker({dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'});

    });
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: First of all in your code there's an " extra at the end...

Comment: I forgot to say I'm using symfony that's why I can use (") in my code.. And it's working on me :)

Answer (score 1):

Remember that in your code there's an extra " at the end... 
If the dateFormat is incorrect the date that will show is: blank or today's date. The user instead of inserting the date written, will select it from the calendar.

Comment: Sorry guys I already edit my code.... I remove the extra code..
All I want is There will be an alert saying Invalid date format

Answer (score 0):

Why you just don't bind an event handler to the change-event?

```
$('#BirthDate').datepicker({
  dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
  onSelect: function() {
    doSomeValidation($(this).getDate());
  }
});
```

If you do not want to validate it on the fly you can access the value afterwards as well.

```
var date = $('#BirthDate').datepicker("getDate")
```

Or is your question "How to validate dates in javascript" ?